# How to customize ZonedDateatime in Kafka message using danielwegener Kafka appender

Tags: java, apache-kafka, logstash

I am using github.danielwegener.logback.kafka.kafkaappender to publish application logs or  messages on Apache Kafka.The  message includes the some string fields and ZonedDateatime java8 fields. But when  message logged in kafka it produces incorrect ZonedDateatime. Means it's logged exatra ZonedDateatime attributes and displaying large json. How I can customize datetime using Kafka appender?

Comment: Why not use log4j2 kafka appenders?

Comment: I have to print the message in kibana using the logstash.

Comment: Okay. You didn't say anything about logstash, only logback... I'm just suggesting that you can skip logstash and format the data however you want in log4j2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved. I have found the PrettyPrintingJsonGeneratorDecorator class. Using this class I am able to format the timestamp and other fields.